# Raspberry Pi camera for underwater movies and pictures

Tags: raspicam

I want to build some kind of submarine or just put Raspberry with camera in sealed jar with ballast and do some underwater hobby research in river or lake and make some fish pictures, movies etc.

I just want to know if Raspberry Pi camera module is good enough to see anything underwater, or shall I buy some high quality webcam to see anything.

Anyone tried something like this?

I guess I will need strong light. Will 3W power LED with be enough to see fish from 2 meters or shall I start experiments with more powerful led, like 10W or more?

Comment: If you want a rough idea how good the camera is then try using your smartphone, the module used on the Pi camera is very similar to that used in phones. The only advantage of using a USB webcam I can see is being able to purchase one that has autofocus.

Comment: I would suggest getting a Pi and a camera, and your lights, and doing some experiments. The camera will be good enough - it's a 5 megapixel sensor. In terms of lights, you need to bear in mind the clarity of the water.